# multiple slider crashes when switching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

slider crashes when I add slider # 2 to  in html but it works fine when I delete the second  section. My goal is to control 2 separate sliders independently.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Free Html Modules - Alpha Universe</title>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .aspect-three-two {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .aspect-three-two:before {
            display: block;
            content: "";
            width: 100%;
            padding-top: 66.66667%;
        }

        .aspect-three-two>div,
        .aspect-three-two>img,
        .aspect-three-two>.card,
        .aspect-three-two>.card-post,
        .aspect-three-two>.au-slider-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }

        .aspect-three-two>.card {
            min-height: 0;
        }

        .aspect-three-two>img {
            top: 50%;
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }

        .au-slider {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        .au-slider__container {
            max-width: 1240px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .au-slider__items {
            position: absolute;
            width: 80%;
            height: 80%;
            display: inline-block;
            -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
        }

        .au-slider__items.main-pos .au-slider__item {
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(6.51%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .042)), color-stop(9.485%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .089)), color-stop(12.25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .147)), color-stop(14.805%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .213)), color-stop(17.185%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .283)), color-stop(19.425%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .357)), color-stop(21.56%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .433)), color-stop(23.625%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .511)), color-stop(25.62%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .591)), color-stop(27.545%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .672)), color-stop(29.435%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .753)), color-stop(31.29%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .834)), color-stop(33.145%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .917)), color-stop(35%, white), color-stop(65%, white), color-stop(66.855%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .917)), color-stop(68.71%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .834)), color-stop(70.565%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .753)), color-stop(72.455%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .672)), color-stop(74.38%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .591)), color-stop(76.375%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .511)), color-stop(78.44%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .433)), color-stop(80.575%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .357)), color-stop(82.815%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .283)), color-stop(85.195%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .213)), color-stop(87.75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .147)), color-stop(90.515%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .089)), color-stop(93.49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .042)), color-stop(96.71%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .011)), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
            background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .011) 3.29%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .042) 6.51%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .089) 9.485%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .147) 12.25%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .213) 14.805%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .283) 17.185%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .357) 19.425%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .433) 21.56%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .511) 23.625%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .591) 25.62%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .672) 27.545%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .753) 29.435%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .834) 31.29%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .917) 33.145%, white 35%, white 65%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .917) 66.855%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .834) 68.71%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .753) 70.565%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .672) 72.455%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .591) 74.38%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .511) 76.375%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .433) 78.44%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .357) 80.575%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .283) 82.815%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .213) 85.195%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .147) 87.75%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .089) 90.515%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .042) 93.49%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .011) 96.71%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
        }

        .au-slider__item {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out .2s;
            transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out .2s;
        }

        .au-slider__figure {
            position: absolute;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .au-slider__img {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
            z-index: 2;
            display: block;
            -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
            -webkit-transition: width .3s ease-in-out .3s;
            transition: width .3s ease-in-out .3s;
        }

        .au-slider__caption {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
            -webkit-transition: bottom .2s ease-in-out, right .2s ease-in-out, width .2s ease-in-out, opacity .1s ease-in-out;
            transition: bottom .2s ease-in-out, right .2s ease-in-out, width .2s ease-in-out, opacity .1s ease-in-out;
            width: 100%;
            padding-top: 4px;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .au-slider__video-wrapper {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .au-slider__video-wrapper iframe {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
        }

        .au-slider__nav {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            height: 80%;
            width: 100%;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-flex;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-pack: justify;
            -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            -moz-justify-content: space-between;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .au-slider__nav-item {
            height: 100%;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-flex;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            -moz-align-items: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: white;
            z-index: 4;
        }

        .au-slider__nav-item--prev {
            padding-right: 3%;
        }

        .au-slider__nav-item--next {
            padding-left: 3%;
        }

        .au-slider__next,
        .au-slider__prev {
            padding: 4px;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 90%;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -moz-flex;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
            -moz-align-items: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .au-slider .main-pos {
            margin-left: 10% !important;
            z-index: 20;
            background-size: 0 0;
        }

        .au-slider .main-pos .au-slider__caption {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .au-slider .left-pos,
        .au-slider .right-pos {
            opacity: .3;
            z-index: 3;
            -webkit-transform: scale(.8);
            transform: scale(.8);
        }

        .au-slider .left-pos .au-slider__video-wrapper,
        .au-slider .right-pos .au-slider__video-wrapper {
            pointer-events: none;
        }

        .au-slider .left-pos {
            margin-left: -4% !important;
        }

        .au-slider .left-pos .au-slider__img {
            left: 0;
            -webkit-transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateX(0) translateY(-50%);
        }

        .au-slider .back-pos {
            margin-left: 10% !important;
            opacity: 0;
            -webkit-transform: scale(.3);
            transform: scale(.3);
        }

        .au-slider .right-pos {
            margin-left: 24% !important;
        }

        .au-slider .right-pos .au-slider__img {
            left: 100%;
            -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(-50%);
        }

        .au-photo__meta {
            list-style: none;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            padding-left: 0;
            padding-top: 4px;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .au-photo__meta-item {
            font-family: "SST W01 Roman", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #676767 !important;
            font-size: .75rem;
            line-height: 1.8;
            letter-spacing: .07em;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="html-template-emea-image-carousel">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h2 class="text-center mb-4" data-label="Module Heading">Gallery</h2>
            <div class="aspect-three-two au-slider__container">
                <div>
                    <ul class="au-slider">

    <li class="au-slider__items" data-slide-id="1">
    <div class="au-slider__item">
        <figure class="au-slider__figure">
            <img class="au-slider__img" src="https://placeimg.com/1600/1066/any?v=1" alt="" data-label="Item 1 - Image">
            <div class="au-slider__caption d-none d-md-block">
                <ul class="au-photo__meta">
                    <li class="au-photo__meta-item t-micro text-light" data-label="Item 1 - Caption" >test 1</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </div>
</li>
    <li class="au-slider__items" data-slide-id="2">
    <div class="au-slider__item">
        <figure class="au-slider__figure">
            <img class="au-slider__img" src="https://placeimg.com/1600/1066/any?v=2" alt="" data-label="Item 2 - Image">
            <div class="au-slider__caption d-none d-md-block">
                <ul class="au-photo__meta">
                    <li class="au-photo__meta-item t-micro text-light" data-label="Item 2 - Caption" >test 2 </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </div>
</li>
    <li class="au-slider__items" data-slide-id="3">
    <div class="au-slider__item">
        <figure class="au-slider__figure">
            <img class="au-slider__img" src="https://placeimg.com/1600/1066/any?v=3" alt="" data-label="Item 3 - Image">
            <div class="au-slider__caption d-none d-md-block">
                <ul class="au-photo__meta">
                    <li class="au-photo__meta-item t-micro text-light" data-label="Item 3 - Caption" >test 3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </div>
</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="au-slider__nav">
                        <div class="au-slider__nav-item au-slider__nav-item--prev">
                            <span class="au-prev au-slider__prev icon-arrow-left text-primary" style="font-size: 12px"
                                data-label="Left Arrow (Don't Change)" data-translate="no">&#9664;</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="au-slider__nav-item au-slider__nav-item--next">
                            <span class="au-next au-slider__next icon-arrow-right text-primary" style="font-size: 12px"
                                data-label="Right Arrow (Don't Change)" data-translate="no">&#9654;</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Slider 2-->

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h2 class="text-center mb-4" data-label="Module Heading">Gallery</h2>
            <div class="aspect-three-two au-slider__container">
                <div>
                    <ul class="au-slider">

    <li class="au-slider__items" data-slide-id="1">
    <div class="au-slider__item">
        <figure class="au-slider__figure">
            <img class="au-slider__img" src="https://placeimg.com/1600/1066/any?v=1" alt="" data-label="Item 1 - Image">
            <div class="au-slider__caption d-none d-md-block">
                <ul class="au-photo__meta">
                    <li class="au-photo__meta-item t-micro text-light" data-label="Item 1 - Caption" >test 1</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </div>
</li>
    <li class="au-slider__items" data-slide-id="2">
    <div class="au-slider__item">
        <figure class="au-slider__figure">
            <img class="au-slider__img" src="https://placeimg.com/1600/1066/any?v=2" alt="" data-label="Item 2 - Image">
            <div class="au-slider__caption d-none d-md-block">
                <ul class="au-photo__meta">
                    <li class="au-photo__meta-item t-micro text-light" data-label="Item 2 - Caption" >test 2 </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </div>
</li>
    <li class="au-slider__items" data-slide-id="3">
    <div class="au-slider__item">
        <figure class="au-slider__figure">
            <img class="au-slider__img" src="https://placeimg.com/1600/1066/any?v=3" alt="" data-label="Item 3 - Image">
            <div class="au-slider__caption d-none d-md-block">
                <ul class="au-photo__meta">
                    <li class="au-photo__meta-item t-micro text-light" data-label="Item 3 - Caption" >test 3</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </div>
</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="au-slider__nav">
                        <div class="au-slider__nav-item au-slider__nav-item--prev">
                            <span class="au-prev au-slider__prev icon-arrow-left text-primary" style="font-size: 12px"
                                data-label="Left Arrow (Don't Change)" data-translate="no">&#9664;</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="au-slider__nav-item au-slider__nav-item--next">
                            <span class="au-next au-slider__next icon-arrow-right text-primary" style="font-size: 12px"
                                data-label="Right Arrow (Don't Change)" data-translate="no">&#9654;</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var auSlider = (function () {
            var startItem = 1;

            function init(elem) {
                var thisSwap = swap.bind(elem);
                elem.find('.au-next').click(function () {
                    thisSwap('clockwise');
                });
                elem.find('.au-prev').click(function () {
                    thisSwap('counter-clockwise');
                });
                var sliderInitItems = elem.find('.au-slider__items');
                var sliderInitLength = sliderInitItems.length;
                sliderInitItems.each(function (index, element) {
                    if ($(element).attr('data-slide-id') == 1) {
                        $(element).addClass('main-pos');
                    } else if ($(element).attr('data-slide-id') == 2) {
                        $(element).addClass('right-pos');
                    } else if ($(element).attr('data-slide-id') == (sliderInitLength)) {
                        $(element).addClass('left-pos');
                    } else {
                        $(element).addClass('back-pos');
                    }
                });
                elem.find('.au-slider__items').on('click', function () {
                    if (elem.attr('class') == 'au-slider__items left-pos') {
                        thisSwap('counter-clockwise');
                    } else {
                        thisSwap('clockwise');
                    }
                });
                animateCaption(elem.find('.main-pos'));
                positionCaption(elem.find('.main-pos'));
            }

            function animateCaption(slide, show) {
                if (show === undefined) {
                    show = !0;
                }
                var currentCaption = $(slide).find('.au-slider__caption');
                var captionPos = positionCaption(slide);
                if (show) {
                    captionPos.bottom -= currentCaption.height();
                    captionPos.bottom += "px";
                } else {
                    captionPos.bottom += currentCaption.height();
                    captionPos.bottom += "px";
                }
                currentCaption.css(captionPos);
            }

            function positionCaption(slide) {
                var slideImage = $(slide).find('.au-slider__img');
                var posX = ((slide.width() - slideImage.width()) / 2) + 'px';
                var posY = ((slide.height() - slideImage.height()) / 2 - 4);
                var capWidth;
                if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
                    capWidth = slideImage.width() + 'px';
                } else {
                    posX = "auto";
                    capWidth = "100%";
                }
                return {
                    right: posX,
                    bottom: posY,
                    width: capWidth,
                };
            }

            function swap(action) {
                var direction = action;
                var position = 0;
                var sliderItems = this.find('.au-slider__items');
                var itemCount = sliderItems.length;
                var resetCount = itemCount;

                function pos(positionvalue) {
                    if (positionvalue != 'leftposition') {
                        position++;
                        if ((startItem + position) > resetCount) {
                            position = 1 - startItem;
                        }
                    }
                    if (positionvalue == 'leftposition') {
                        position = startItem - 1;
                        if (position < 1) {
                            position = itemCount;
                        }
                    }
                    return position;
                }
                if (direction == 'counter-clockwise') {
                    var leftitem = this.find('.left-pos').attr('data-slide-id') - 1;
                    if (leftitem === 0) {
                        leftitem = itemCount;
                    }

                    this.find('.right-pos').removeClass('right-pos').addClass('back-pos');
                    this.find('.main-pos').removeClass('main-pos').addClass('right-pos');
                    this.find('.left-pos').removeClass('left-pos').addClass('main-pos');
                    this.find('[data-slide-id="' + leftitem + '"]').removeClass('back-pos').addClass('left-pos');
                    this.find('.left-pos .au-slider__caption').css('bottom', 0);
                    this.find('.left-pos .au-slider__caption').css('bottom', 0);

                    startItem--;

                    if (startItem < 1) {
                        startItem = itemCount;
                    }
                    animateCaption($('.main-pos'));
                    animateCaption($('.left-pos'), false);
                }
                if (direction === 'clockwise' || direction === '' || direction === null) {

                    var rightItem = (itemCount < 4) ? 3 : parseInt(this.find('.right-pos').attr('data-slide-id')) + 1;

                    if (rightItem > itemCount) {
                        rightItem = 1;
                    }

                    this.find('.left-pos').removeClass('left-pos').addClass('back-pos');
                    this.find('.main-pos').removeClass('main-pos').addClass('left-pos');
                    this.find('.right-pos').removeClass('right-pos').addClass('main-pos');
                    if (itemCount < 4) {
                        this.find('.back-pos').removeClass('back-pos').addClass('right-pos');
                    } else {
                        this.find('[data-slide-id="' + rightItem + '"]').removeClass('back-pos').addClass('right-pos');
                    }

                    this.find('.left-pos .au-slider__caption').css('bottom', 0);
                    this.find('.left-pos .au-slider__caption').css('bottom', 0);

                    startItem++;
                    position = 0;
                    if (startItem > itemCount) {
                        startItem = 1;
                    }
                    animateCaption($('.main-pos'));
                    animateCaption($('.right-pos'), false);
                }
                animateCaption(this.find('.main-pos'));
            }
            return {
                init: init,
                positionCaption: positionCaption
            };
        })();
        auSlider.init($('.au-slider__container'));
        setInterval(function () { 

            var css = auSlider.positionCaption($('.main-pos'));

            $(".main-pos .au-slider__caption").css({
                right  : css.right,
                bottom : css.bottom - 25,
                width : css. width
            });

        }, 200);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

2. The slider section is under the  tag

[codepen link](https://codepen.io/yeolgun/pen/mdyjvXV)
thanks in advance for your help.. (:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppMQS.png)

slider crashes when I add slider # 2 to  in html but it works fine when I delete the second  section. My goal is to control 2 separate sliders independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yunus,

The problem is happening, because you mount the slider like this: `auSlider.init($('.au-slider__container'));`, hence the selector pick all the elements with this class, and somehow it gets lost after you start moving the map.

You can solve this, by mounting one by one, like this:

```
auSlider.init($('.au-slider__container:eq(0)'));
auSlider.init($('.au-slider__container:eq(1)'));
```

Take a look at the fiddle working: https://codepen.io/lessadiogo/pen/BayPbKJ

Cheers,

Diogo

Comment: for dynamic 

function auSliderGenerator(){
            
                for(i=0; i < ($('.au-slider__container').length); i++){
                    auSlider.init($('.au-slider__container:eq('+i+')'));
                }
        
        };
        auSliderGenerator();

Comment: Exactly, that's the idea.